# save user session as a variable

Tags: php, session, session-variables

Pretty new to php so bear with me.

I am using a simple template system where i set a variable as [%PLACEHOLDER%] that then outputs the data stored in the variable on the template page when ever i use the [%TAG%] associated with it.

I do this as i like to separate all of the php and html making it easier for different themes and templates to be created with out a user knowing php.

a simple example is :

```
(object) $tpl = new Tmpl( array( 'file' => 'templates/header.tpl' ) );

$tpl->replace( '[%USER%]', $user);
echo $tpl->output();
```

Now this all works fine. what i want to do is save a user session as a variable for me to assign a placeholder tag to it.

I use the following code with a php page

```
<div id="logedin" class="<?php echo (isset($_SESSION['sess_user_id'])) ? 'show' : 'hide'; ?>">
Welcome, <?php echo $_SESSION["sess_username"] ?>
```

basically if the user is logged in the div id 'logedin' is shown. if not its hidden.

there are 2 css styles i use for this.

```
.show{
 display: block;
}
.hide{
 display: none;
}
```

what i want to do is save the (isset($_SESSION['sess_user_id'])) ? 'show' : 'hide'; as a variable i can then assign as a placeholder.

something like this (but this obviously does not work hence me asking the question)

```
$sessionclassshow = (isset($_SESSION['sess_user_id'])) ? 'show' : 'hide';
$sessionclasshide = (isset($_SESSION['sess_user_id'])) ? 'hide' : 'show';
```

then i assign them as a place holder like this

```
$tpl->replace( '[%CLASSSHOW%]', $sessionclassshow);
$tpl->replace( '[%CLASSHIDE%]', $sessionclasshide);
```

so anywhere in my template file i can show or hide a div dependent on if the user is loged in or not.

```
<div id="topmenu" class="[%SESSIONHIDE%]"><a href="login.html">Login</a></div>
<div id="welcome" class="[%SESSIONSHOW%]">welcome [%USER%]</div>
```

so if the user is logged in hide the 'topmenu' div and show the 'welcome' div and vice versa.

I hope i have explained everything well enough and appreciate any help

thanks
lee

Comment: You can add a column (to whatever table holds user information, such as username and login_id, etc.) called 'onlinestatus' (or something similar). When the user logs on, 'onlinestatus' is set to 'online', then set your css classes or inline styles based on this (silimiarly, when user logs off, set onlinestatus to 'offline')

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob - And what happens when the user doesn't logout and the session ends?

Comment: Sorry...didn't see Javascript wasn't a tag. Using Javascript I would set an inactivity timeout of x minutes --> auto logout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assign them like this :

```
$tpl->replace( '[%CLASSSHOW%]', $sessionclassshow);
$tpl->replace( '[%CLASSHIDE%]', $sessionclasshide);
```

But in the template you use them using `%SESSIONXXXX%` when you should use `%CLASSXXXX%`(as in their declaration).

This should work :

```
<div id="topmenu" class="[%CLASSHIDE%]"><a href="login.html">Login</a></div>
<div id="welcome" class="[%CLASSSHOW%]">welcome [%USER%]</div>
```

Comment: How stupid of me. i changed the name and didn't do the same in the template file. thanks for pointing this out it works perfectly now